# Unable to use Jira-Ruby gem in "After" hook in test code

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, jira-rest-api

I am integrating jira-ruby gem in my testing framework(Ruby, BDD[using cucumber]) to report a bug on failing testcase using rest api. When i used below mentioned code in 'After' hook getting error : **SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)**

### Code:

```
After do 
  options ={
    :username     => 'xyzsingh',
    :password     => 'abcsingh',
    :site         => 'https://xyzsingh.atlassian.net/',
    :context_path => '',
    :ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE, 
    :auth_type => :basic, 
    :read_timeout => 120
  }

  client = JIRA::Client.new(options)
  issue = client.Issue.build
  issue.save({
    "fields"=>{
      "summary"=>"****",
      "description"=> "Not able to  report bug",
      "project"=>{"key"=>"****"},
      "issuetype"=>{"name"=>"Bug"}
    }
  })
end
```

---

Also when i used same code some where else in framework it works and it creates bug in my jira account. It seems that some kind of restriction are there in 'After' hook.Can anyone help me on this??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the stand-alone code that would make use of that gem to successfully log a sample bug in Jira?

Then, where are you requiring the gem and which line of the code you showed us is generating the error? 

Lastly, it appears they have a SLACK channel (see the read-me at https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby) which might be a better place to ask for help with that gem, as I see no SO tag for it.

Comment: Also after what? Typically you would specify on scenario.failed.